# Use of functions in where clause in feathers

Tags: postgis, feathersjs

The problem is that I need to include a function in the where clause of the SQL generated by the feathers

If the where clause is assigned only the function the SQL is generated correct, but I of cause missing the status part

```
options.where=fn

SELECT 
   "id", "feature_name", "status", "priority", "label", "st_asgeojson" FROM "gis34_registration"."geojson_tasks" AS "geojson_tasks" 
WHERE 
   ST_Intersects(geom, ST_transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(12.370044675467057, 55.73287419556607, 12.385791865781385, 55.7422305387, 4326), 25832))
```

This is the sql that I need feathers to generate

```
options.where.status='Registreret'
options.where.fn=fn

SELECT 
   "id", "feature_name", "status", "priority", "label", "st_asgeojson" FROM "gis34_registration"."geojson_tasks" AS "geojson_tasks" 
WHERE 
   status = 'Registreret' AND 
   fn = ST_Intersects(geom, ST_transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(12.370044675467057, 55.73287419556607, 12.385791865781385, 55.7422305387, 4326), 25832))
```

This is the sql that I need feathers to generate

```
SELECT 
   "id", "feature_name", "status", "priority", "label", "st_asgeojson" FROM "gis34_registration"."geojson_tasks" AS "geojson_tasks" 
WHERE 
   status = 'Registreret' AND 
   ST_Intersects(geom, ST_transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(12.370044675467057, 55.73287419556607, 12.385791865781385, 55.7422305387, 4326), 25832))
```

How do i get the feathers to generate SQL with a function and attributes together?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use the predefined porperty $and. The code below generates the required SQL

```
options.where.status='Registreret'
options.where.$and=fn
```